# Single Sign ON recommendations

Tags: single-sign-on

For SSO, we have Ping Fed as IDP that interacts with our AD. But when Ping Fed fails, users cant access Salesforce even if Salesforce is running fine.

Any methods recommended to help users login, when the IDP is down? We have a large user group for which SSO has been implemented. Tx

Answer (score 0):

By definition, your IDP is just that - your identity *provider*. It provides the identity for your users. You outsource that function of Salesforce (and other service providers) to it when setting up SSO. You need a strategy for keeping your IDP (and AD) servers up. If your IDP is subject to downtime, you probably shouldn't be using it as your IDP.

You could have a process for disabling federated authentication within Salesforce when your IDP is down, so that users could login with a Salesforce username/password, but that is a problematic workaround if you want actual federated identity.

Comment: The case is, our investment on IDP is long term. So changing that is a risk. hence looking at an easy way by which users can access SFDC, when IDP is down.. any smart ways to achieve this?

Comment: OR will this work..  Have an alternate custom Login page that has a button. Click the button wherein a webservice is invoked that passes through a common password for login, when user email matches what is maintained in SFDC.

Comment: You could do that... but that would be rife with risks since you're essentially rolling your own security. Honestly at that point you'd be 100% better off by not using SSO and just having everyone manage a separate SFDC username/password.

Answer (score 0):

[Salesforce best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_tips.htm&language=en_US)

There's an administrative permission called "Is Single Sign-On Enabled". If that is unchecked, then the users should be able to login from login.salesforce.com. When it's checked they are required to use the external IdP. Best practice says leave it unchecked for Admins. You could leave it unchecked for all profiles.

You could also create a permission set for all Users that has Single Sign-On enabled, and when your IdP goes down, alter that permission set allowing users to use login.salesforce.com.

Better solution, use a high reliability IdP!

Comment: Hi John.. a question here. If i uncheck "Is Single sign ON Enabled" and have users use login.salesforce.com.. what password can they use? Will their NT login and password work for this manual login attempt?

Comment: Hi Manoj, I'm pretty sure that their NT Login and Salesforce native passwords will be independent. That's why doing that is not best practice.... the user has to maintain two passwords! Of course if the user selects the same password for Salesforce and the IdP it's easy to remember, but that's also not best practice.